# Should I know Gate and Policy for work with Passport Authorization

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-6, laravel-authorization

I want to make API authorization using Laravel Passport, should I use Gate and Policy or there is another way for Passport?

Comment: Is there a reason you doubt gates/policies are appropriate?

Comment: can I use them with Passport ? There is no clear explanation for how to using them with Passport int the Laravel docs

Comment: Sure. There's no explanation of that because it doesn't really work that way - they don't need a specific integration to work together. They just do.